# Issue with pandoc versions

Tags: anaconda, conda, pandoc

I am trying to run `pandoc` and am getting the `Unknown writer: gfm` issue, which seems to be fixed in the latest release of `pandoc`. However, I am unsure how to fix the versioning issue.

When I do `pandoc -v` I get:

```
pandoc 1.19.2.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.4, texmath 0.9, skylighting 0.1.1.4
Default user data directory: /Users/MYSELF/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2016 John MacFarlane
Web:  http://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness
for a particular purpose.
```

Don't ask me why, but I had ran `brew uninstall pandoc` and `pip uninstall pandoc`, so both now say there is no current installed `pandoc`. However, when I do `type pandoc` I get

```
pandoc is hashed (/anaconda3/bin/pandoc)
```

Meaning it depends on the `anaconda` installation. To remove it (or update it) I tried using `conda update pandoc`. I never went on with the removal since `conda remove pandoc` asks to remove many other things that I need (e.g. `jupyter`, `nbconvert`, `jupyterlab`, `anaconda-2018`).

How do I solve the issue of `pandoc`? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well... updating `anaconda`, `conda`, and then `pandoc` solved the issue...

Comment: The problem was that older versions of `nbconvert` specifically depended on older versions of `pandoc`. I think with a recent release of `nbconvert` they updated their dependency to be able to use newer versions of `pandoc`. Probably when you updated `anaconda`, it updated `nbconvert` and then allowed the update of `pandoc`